# regular expression to select city names from string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression in PHP for selecting city names from long string.

Basic pseudocode is this:

```
if ( 
     "v"   or   "V"     or 
     "vo"  or   "Vo"    or 
     "pri" or   "Pri"   or 
     "od"  or   "Od"    or 
     "z"   or   "Z"     or  
     "na"  or   "Na"    or 
     "nad" or   "Nad"   or 
     "do"  or   "Do"    or
     "pod" or   "Pod"  


is_before "String" or 
          "String String" or 
          "String string String" or 
          "String String String"
)
do 
{
   add "String String String" to array"

}
```

Examples:

My cousin lives pri City. - pass { City }

Ja som bol vo Velkom Krtisi. - pass { Velkom Krtisi }

Dnes som jedol palacinky v Dubnici nad Vahom. - pass { Dubnici nad Vahom }

My try:

```
preg_match_all('/..[V|v|pri|Pri|Od|od|Do|do|Z|z|na|Na|Nad|nad][ ][A-Z]{0,10}/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does the last example yield a pass? There is none of the mentioned words in front of the city name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Whenever you use square brackets you can match only one character. Therefore

```
[V|v|pri|Pri|Od|od|Do|do|Z|z|na|Na|Nad|nad]
```

is equal to

```
[|VvpriOddDoZznaN]
```

Note that `|` is just another literal character in there. Additionally, what's with the two `..` you start off with? They just give you (and require) two more characters in the match. Finally, three words are best matched by `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+){1,3}`.

Lastly, you need to capture the part that you want (by using parentheses):

```
preg_match_all('/(?:V|v|pri|Pri|Od|od|Do|do|Z|z|na|Na|Nad|nad)((?:\s+[A-Za-z]+){1,3})/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Now `$matches[1]` will contain all the cities (including the leading space) and their offsets in the string.

You can probably shorten this by using the `i` modifier (case-insensitivity). Of course, this will allow `pRI` for instance, but maybe that's not a problem. Also, you might want to add a word boundary, so that things like `abcdefv foobar` don't trigger a match (due to the trailing `v`):

```
preg_match_all('/\b(?:vo?|pri|od|do|z|nad?)((?:\s+[a-z]+){1,3})/i', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Of course, if you leave out the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`, you just get the cities which fits your pseudo code better.

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/E8bqxq)